# How to align the text in a wx.ListBox using wxPython?

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython, center, alignment

I want the text of the ListBox to be centered, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the default ListBox won't work for that. Try the VListBox instead.